# Fetch a cert using python3 from a server that requires client auth without authenticating?

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, openssh

Is it possible to only fetch a cert using python3 from a server that requires client auth without authenticating?

There's a server in my environment requiring a client ssl cert to authenticate. If you don't have one, when you connect with openssl you'll be able to fetch the certificate but get an error: [Post with details](https://serverfault.com/questions/950239/openssl-1-0-2q-error-at-finished-message-error140790e5ssl-routinesssl23-wr?noredirect=1#comment1235158_950239). The error occurs late in the handshake.

If I try with python using the ssl module:

```
hostname = 'serverwithclientauth'
# PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT requires valid cert chain and hostname
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
context.load_verify_locations('path/to/cabundle.pem')

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
        print(ssock.version())
```

(which is basically copy/paste from: [Python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html))), wrap_socket fails. I am wondering if the ssl sequence can be broken down into smaller chunks such that I can terminate after the server sends the cert to the client.

I have tried just going for:

```
ssl.get_server_certificate((host,port))
```

but even just that bit fails for this host (others without client auth requirement work great!).